# Insert A numpy multi dimensional array inside another 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I already have an array with shape (1, 224, 224), a single channel image. I want to change that to (1, 1, 224, 224). I have been trying

```
newarr.shape
#(1,224,224)
arr = np.array([])
np.append(arr, newarr, 1)
```

I always get this 
IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1). If i remove the axis as 0 , then the array gets flattened . What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just do : `newarr[np.newaxis]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dimension of 1 is arbitrary, so it sounds like you want to simply reshape the array. This can accomplished by:

```
newarr.shape = (1, 1, 244, 244)
```

or

```
newarr = newarr[None]
```

Comment: Explicit assignment to `.shape` is very nice, I wasn't aware of this feature. This can apparently be used as general reshaping, e.g. `newarr.shape = (2, 2, 56, 224)`, and it will raise a `ValueError` if the number of elements is not preserved.

Comment: The `newarr = newarr[:, ...]` trick does not seem to have any effect on `newarr` at all.

Comment: @jmd_dk Whoops, I ment `None` instead of `:`. The question is now fixed. Yes, this can not be used to modify the overall size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do an `insert` into a higher dimensional array is

```
bigger_arr = np.zeros((1, 1, 224, 224))
bigger_arr[0,...] = arr
```

In other words, make a target array of the right size, and assign values.

`np.append` is a booby trap.  Avoid it.

Occasionally that's a useful way of thinking of this.  But it's simpler, and quicker, to think of this as a `reshape` problem.

```
bigger_arr = arr.reshape(1,1,224,224)
bigger_arr = arr[np.newaxis,...]
arr.shape = (1,1,224,224)   # a picky inplace change
bigger_arr = np.expand_dims(arr, 0)
```

This last one does

```
a.reshape(shape[:axis] + (1,) + a.shape[axis:])
```

which gives an idea of how to deal with dimensions programmatically.